# most optimized way to get number of unique rows in a column spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was doing this MOOC for a spark refresher and came across this problem 
"find the no of unique hosts " in a data frame which was created earlier (Apache log analysis)

the data frame looks like this

```
--------------------+--------------------+------+------------+--------------------+
|                host|                path|status|content_size|                time|
+--------------------+--------------------+------+------------+--------------------+
|  in24.inetnebr.com |/shuttle/missions...|   200|        1839|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|    uplherc.upl.com |                   /|   304|           0|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|    uplherc.upl.com |/images/ksclogo-m...|   304|           0|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|    uplherc.upl.com |/images/MOSAIC-lo...|   304|           0|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|    uplherc.upl.com |/images/USA-logos...|   304|           0|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|ix-esc-ca2-07.ix....|/images/launch-lo...|   200|        1713|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|    uplherc.upl.com |/images/WORLD-log...|   304|           0|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|slppp6.intermind....|/history/skylab/s...|   200|        1687|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|piweba4y.prodigy....|/images/launchmed...|   200|       11853|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|slppp6.intermind....|/history/skylab/s...|   200|        9202|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|slppp6.intermind....|/images/ksclogosm...|   200|        3635|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|ix-esc-ca2-07.ix....|/history/apollo/i...|   200|        1173|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|slppp6.intermind....|/history/apollo/i...|   200|        3047|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|    uplherc.upl.com |/images/NASA-logo...|   304|           0|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|       133.43.96.45 |/shuttle/missions...|   200|       10566|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|kgtyk4.kj.yamagat...|                   /|   200|        7280|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|kgtyk4.kj.yamagat...|/images/ksclogo-m...|   200|        5866|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
|    d0ucr6.fnal.gov |/history/apollo/a...|   200|        2743|1995-08-01 00:00:...|
```

Now I have tried 3 methods to find  no of unique hosts

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
unique_host_count = logs_df.agg(func.countDistinct(col("host"))).head()[0]
```

this runs in about 0.72 seconds

```
unique_host_count = logs_df.select("host").distinct().count()
```

this runs in 0.57 seconds

```
unique_host = logs_df.groupBy("host").count()
unique_host_count = unique_host.count()
```

this runs in 0.62 seconds

So my question is are there any  much better alternative than the second one, I assumed `distinct` is a expensive operation but it turned out to be the fastest

```
The data  frame I am using have 

1043177 rows 

spark version  - 1.6.1 
cluster -6 gb memory
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not inefficient. Because it determines all unique values for every partition (don't forget that your data is split among several nodes). After that, it compares those values and picks all the distinct values among all nodes, and that is very easy to parallelize. On the other hand, when you group data, Spark shuffles data, and that is more expensive, cause in most of cases you have to intensively use the network.

Answer (score 1):

You use accomplish it using map & reduce operations:

```
unique_host_count = logs_df.select("host")\
.map(lambda x:  (x, 1))\
.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)\
.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this would cause a shuffle also but it's an option

```
logs_df.dropDuplicates("host").count
```